# Analysis on Cook's distance when residuals are not normal

Tags: regression, residuals, normality-assumption, cooks-distance

I have found in the slides of my course about linear regression a sentence that I couldn't understand properly which is the following one: "If residuals are not normal, analysis on Cook's distances is questionable".

I have only thought that when residuals are normal distributed, the  ([Cook's distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook%27s_distance)) follow a Fisher distribution. However even with this idea the sentence is not yet clear to me.
Does anyone know something about this?

Comment: Too short for an answer: You can still calculate Cook's distance, but its statistical properties will depend on the distribution.